# Amazon OpenSearch Service stably or less downtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudfront, devops, amazon-elasticache

Can anyone point out, What is the best way for the elastic search to run stably? We frequently get messages about it requiring updates and that an update requires some downtime.

Could we have 2 instances running and just change the DNS record to point to the one not being updated?

Is changing the existing Amazon OpenSearch Service instance types to Graviton2 using a blue/green deployment process, will minimize downtime?

What is the best approach here?